# formatting header in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am new to this Community as well as in programming too.
 I need to create a  different headers in my website and each header should be formatted according to my need.

i don't know what's wrong in it should i use id for calling a header or what tactic should i use for good and efficient practice? 
 If Yes,how should i implement this?
Here is my Sample,please tell me the mistakes i am making? 
**HTML:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">    
<h6 class="text-center"><a href="#"></a>PEOPLE-THINGS RECOMENDATION</h6>

    <h6><a href="#">Actors/movies</a></h6>
</div></div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.jumbotron h6{
  position:relative;
  bottom:37px;
  color:#815cb8;
  font-weight:normal;
 }
.jumbotron h6 {
  position:relative;
  bottom:32px;
  font-weight:normal;}
```

My header is not changing at all and whenever i try to add new one it also exhibits the same features.

Thankyou So much.

Comment: I think you simple want first h6 in center, right?

Comment: y alignment is not the concern, h6 is not forming a unique header,its inheriting the above h6 css style sheet. I want to make it different by changing its position or  calling it by different id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are styling two same selectors this is why nothing is changing. You should have two different selectors for `h6` in order to have two different styles for them.

Here is the Html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">    
        <h6 class="text-center first-heading"><a href="#"></a>PEOPLE-THINGS RECOMENDATION</h6>
        <h6 class="second-heading"><a href="#">Actors/movies</a></h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.jumbotron h6{
    position:relative;
    color:#815cb8;
    font-weight:normal;
}

.first-heading {
    text-align: center;
}

.second-heading a {
    color:black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/4d9jqxeu/

Comment: Thanks @Viktor,  could you please tell me can i use Id on my header and call it in css ?

Comment: you can use `id="heading1"` and style it in the css in this way: `#heading1 { color: black; text-align: center; }`. If my answer has helped you please approve it and vote for it.

Comment: Yes Viktor give me a mint i'll approve it. And secondly if you think that my question is constructive and help someone out there then please Vote for it too :)

Answer (score 0):

i think if you need to override the font size and other things in h6 you dont need a h6 then put a div and write your css in it as shown below

```css
.jumbotron .header1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #815cb8;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.jumbotron .header2 {
  color: #f715aa;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.jumbotron a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #237bba;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="header1">
      <a href="#"></a>PEOPLE-THINGS RECOMENDATION</div>

    <div class="header2"><a href="#">Actors/movies</a>PEOPLE-THINGS RECOMENDATION</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's alot man, i need to make around 17 heading's in my jumbotron don't you think it would be time consuming,I am looking for an efficient?

Comment: you need to be specific are those all headings gonna be different in style like if structure is going to remain same you can keep css skin separate and just keep applying relevant css class on same structure when needed.you don't need to create 17 headings just keep changing the css but m still not sure about your requirement